# How to Export DataGridView data to PDF?

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

We have a WinForm application and data grid view control with data in the following format.
Is it possible to export this data to a PDF file preserving the format exactly as given in the picture. [image]

Comment: You can try to copy the clipbard the grid and paste it into an excel file, if this works run by the same procedure code. 
I in my WPF grid I was forced to do so. When you have a excel file you can convert this in PDF

Comment: @daniele3004 This is a good suggestion (all my customers might not have EXCEL). But isn't there any third part tool which enables direct export to PDF preserving the format.

Comment: Ok, you need the normal libraries to produce PDF files at runtime ... 
If you use WinForm should not be difficult to find even FREE. 
I personally did everything before hand then I decided to buy one from a vendor components WF and WPF

Comment: Try to search here or similar topics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601145/c-winform-creating-pdf

Comment: @daniele3004 the issue is not getting exporting the grid to PDF, but rather how to get it formatted the way it is given in the screenshot above.

Comment: What you want to do need to use a library for creating a PDF through code and runtime produce that type of layout

Comment: Yes exactly. That is what is the question all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved using Reporting tool RDLC, as we could not find any good solution

Answer (score 0):

You need a library Itext
The ItextLibrary is the most famous library to create each type of PDF at runtime
See this example and find the guide for Itext Library for PDF
This library contains a method for create table with rowspane and colspan as you wish

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp